# How can I review the nsq source code in intellij?

Tags: go, nsq

I download and build up the nsq src code and i wanna to navigate the src code by intellij 14.0 golang plugin. How can I import the whole nsq project into intellij without errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the code with go get you can create an IntelliJ project with your $GOPATH as the root of the project. Then you can navigate to the $GOPATH/src/github.com/bitly folders to see the code.

Comment: While I just followed your advise, but there are still some errors in my workspace, the ide cannot resolve some package.

Answer (score 0):

While the upcoming version is stable, some things might not work, hence it's currently released under github releases section here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases if you have any issues with it, please search for duplicates and if you can't find any, feel free to open one. Also be sure to read the readme :)

Hope it helps.